# .NET console application embedded Database

Tags: .net, console-application, localdb

I am working with a Console Application which is pointing to a Database installed in local SQL Server.

Now I have to send this console application to a Tester for testing and he doesn't have SQLcserver installed in his machine.

Is there a way I can use some embedded database within my Console application and it's part of the exe so that the tester is not dependent upon installing database in his machine.

Comment: If the tester has the dev tools you have installed and SSMS, you can transfer and have him run the project and connect to the mdf file using a (localdb)/v11.0 style connection string (depending on version of sql you are running).

Comment: If you don't need all the power of SQL Server, you could also use SQL Server Compact Edition.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299